# Anonymous function vs Named function which is better and why

Tags: javascript

I search on google  but did not find clear answer about anonymous and named function. I am looking for simple answer which one is better any why or its depends on requirement. So I am looking forward to your valuable answer about these topic. Your answer is really help me out to understand this. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1169519

Comment: @Teemu: So which one is better?

Comment: Better? You can't say one is better than another, they are just used for different purposes.

Comment: @vaultah: I am just want an answer which may help me out to understand which one is better. MY Purpose is just to get answered of my queries

Comment: @Teemu: Exactly I just want to know for which purpose shall I use anonymous and for what name function

Comment: My question is not duplicate. In given answer they are talking about difference but I just want to know where to use named and where anonymous

Comment: I use a simple rule: If I'll need the name of the function later, then I use named function, if I won't need the name, I omit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantages of a named function (expression) are:

- makes it more reliable to call the function recursively, since the name becomes a binding inside the function itself.
- can create a better call stack (by using the function name instead of `<anonymous>`

Using a named function (expression) might not be possible if

- you care about IE6, which doesn't handle them properly (it creates two functions)
- you can't think of a name that wouldn't shadow a variable you need to access inside the function